# Sphinx, literalinclude, linenos: How to display the actual line numbers from the source code file on the doc's code snippet?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to document parts of Javascript code on a web page.

I use

```
.. literalinclude:: ../examples/mapviz-step1-simple.html
   :language: javascript
   :lines: 47-51
   :linenos:
```

I get

[image]

The code snippet comes from lines 47-51 of the actual source code file, not 1-5.

How can I display the actual line numbers along with this snippet of code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was not possible when the question was asked in 2011, but since Sphinx 1.3 there is `lineno-start` option. See this enhancement request: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/668.

Current documentation:

- [`literalinclude`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude)
- [`code-block`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block)

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx 1.3 [will have](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/markup/code.html#line-numbers) `lineno-start` feature available just for this purpose.