# How to control lineno in sourcecode directive?

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to write a document which includes a part of source code with line numbers.

Example(whitch I expected):

```
123.  int myFunc() {
124.      return 100;
125.  }
```

When I use sourcecode/code-block directive, line number is always started from 1.

Currently, I tried following methods, but these are not worked.

Is there any way to control line numbers?

A: use 'linenostart' option.

```
.. sourcecode:: cpp
    :linenos:
    :linenostart: 123

    int myFunc() {
        return 100;
    }
```

=> it was result in error "unknown option: lineno"

B: use literal include.

```
.. literalinclude:: my_func.cpp
    :language: cpp
    :linenos:
    :lines: 123-125
```

=> it was result in no error, but line number is start from 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867961/407651

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will waiting for this request to be released.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sphinx, literalinclude, linenos: How to display the actual line numbers from the source code file on the doc's code snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867961/sphinx-literalinclude-linenos-how-to-display-the-actual-line-numbers-from-the)